# FileExist returns false

Tags: vb.net

I have a folder with 700+ .jpgs. I also have a `Textbox` with one filename per line. 
I want to check which file does not exist in the folder, but should be there.

This is my code:

```
Dim Counter As Integer = 0
For Each Line As String In tbFileNames.Lines
    Counter = Counter + 1
    If (IO.File.Exists(tbFolder.Text & "\" & tbFileNames.Lines(Counter - 1).ToString & ".jpg")) = False Then
        tbNotExistingFiles.Text = tbNotExistingFiles.Text & vbNewLine & (tbFileNames.Lines(Counter - 1).ToString)
    Else
    End If
Next
```

Problem: I get more than 300 "missing" files, but there should be only 7. When I search for the output filenames, they are in the folder, so the `FileExists` functions returns `false`, but it shouldn't.

Where is the problem? Is it the amount of files?

Comment: You're looping through the Lines collection, but not using each Line declared in your For loop. You're using a counter instead. I think you should be using the Line variable.

Comment: `For Each Line As String In tbFileNames.Lines If Not File.Exists(Path.Combine(tbFolder.Text, Line & ".jpg")) then tbNotExistingFiles.AppendText(Line & vbNewLine) end if next`. This assumes that `tbFolder.Text` contains the full path to your Images, not just a Folder name.

Answer (score 0):

According to this line:

```vb
If (IO.File.Exists(tbFolder.Text & "\" & tbFileNames.Lines(Counter - 1).ToString & ".jpg")) = False
```

Which can be interpreted as:

- The `tbFolder` TextBox contains the directory's path where the images are located.
- The `tbFileNames` TextBox contains the main and complete file names. One file name per line.
- Appending the extension `& ".jpg"` means that the file names in the `tbFileNames` TextBox are without extensions. And,
- You need to get a list of the missing files in that directory and show the result in the `tbNotExistingFiles` TextBox.

If my interpretation is correct, then you can achieve that using the extension methods like:

```vb
Imports System.IO
'...

Dim missingFiles = tbFileNames.Lines.
    Select(Function(x) $"{x.ToLower}.jpg").
    Except(Directory.GetFiles(tbFolder.Text).
    Select(Function(x) Path.GetFileName(x.ToLower)))

tbNotExistingFiles.Text = String.Join(ControlChars.NewLine, missingFiles)
```

Or by a [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) query:

```vb
Dim missingFiles = From x In tbFileNames.Lines
                    Where (
                        Aggregate y In Directory.EnumerateFiles(tbFolder.Text)
                            Where Path.GetFileName(y).ToLower.Equals($"{x.ToLower}.jpg")
                                Into Count()
                        ) = 0
                    Select x

'Alternative to tbNotExistingFiles.Text = ...
tbNotExistingFiles.Lines = missingFiles.ToArray
```

Note that, there's no need nor use for the `File.Exists(..)` function in the preceding snippets. Just in case you prefer your approach using `For..Loop` and `File.Exists(..)` function, then you can do:

```vb
Dim missingFiles As New List(Of String)

For Each line In tbFileNames.Lines
    If Not File.Exists(Path.Combine(tbFolder.Text, $"{line}.jpg")) Then
        missingFiles.Add(line)
    End If
Next

tbNotExistingFiles.Lines = missingFiles.ToArray
```